# Instantiate a class with two parents

Tags: design

Suppose I have TypeA and TypeB classes, which are totally different, but both hold an list of TypeC objects.

```
Class TypeA { List<TypeC> cs; }
Class TypeB { List<TypeC> cs; }
```

Throuth all of it's life cycle, a TypeC instance is belong to a one single TypeA instance and a one single TypeB instance, which cannot be changed.

My question is how to create a new TypeC instance and associate it to TypeA and TypeB instances?

simple solution would be:

```
ConstructorOfC(typeA, typeB) {
    typeA.insertC(this);
    typeB.insertC(this);
}
```

the drawbacks of this approach is that C is aware and depend on TypeA and TypeB classes. I also expose an insert method, which I do not want since insert should be only upon creation, but this method can be called at any time.

Another solution can be:

```
TypeA: createTypeC() {
     this.cs.insert(new TypeC());
}
```

which would work if typeC had a single parent, but it's not the case.

Answer (score 1):

You need some repository of C's to determine the scope of "All Type C's" I would suggest

```
Dictionary<TypeC,Tuple<TypeA,TypeB>> allCs = new Dictionary<TypeC,Tuple<TypeA,TypeB>>();
```

the only question is where to put it. Since you don't want TypeC to be dependent on the other types it will have to be at the application level.

I would add a Factory class to ensure that all new TypeCs are added to the collection and make the collection a singleton within the factory class.

```
public class CFactory : ICChecker
{
    private static Dictionary<TypeC,Tuple<TypeA,TypeB>> allCs = new Dictionary<TypeC,Tuple<TypeA,TypeB>>();

    public TypeC CreateTypeC(TypeA a, TypeB b)
    {
        var c = new TypeC();
        a.insert(c);
        b.insert(c)
        allCs.AddWithValue(c, new Tuple<TypeA,TypeB>(a,b));
    }

    public bool IsCAlreadyAssigned(TypeC c)
    {
        return allCs.ContainsKey(c);
    }
}
```

now in your A and B

```
public class TypeA
{
    private readonly ICChecker checker;
    public TypeA(ICChecker checker) { this.checker = checker; }
    public void insert(TypeC c)
    {
        if(this.checker.IsCAlreadyAssigned(c) { throw new Exception("NO!"); }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what you described, I think this is actually somewhat simple.  For clarity, I'll call each type a bit differently. It's not clear

```
class Father {
  List<Child> children;

  public void addChild(Child child) {
    if (child.father == this) {
      children.add(child);
    }
  }
}

class Mother {
  List<Child> children;
  public void addChild(Child child) {
    if (child.mother == this) {
      children.add(child);
    }
  }
}

class Child {
  Father father;
  Mother mother;

  public Father getFather() { return this.father; }
  private void setFather(Father f) { 
      if(this.father == null) {
        this.father = f;
        f.addChild(this);
      } // throw an exception if you want
  }
  public Mother getMother() { return this.mother; }
  private void setMother(Mother m) {
     if (this.mother == null) {
       this.mother = m;
       m.addChild(this);
     }
  }

  public Child(Father f, Mother m) {
     this.setFather(f);
     this.setMother(m);
  }
}
```

This ensures that only the child can set its parents and only once, and the parents can only add a child if that child has them as a parent.